# Holomorphic Differentials on a non-singular curve.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, divisors-algebraic-geometry, holomorphic-bundles

So I've been working on this for an exam I have coming up, and I'm not sure if I really understand.

If I have a curve defined by some homogeneous polynomial $P$, I can show that the canonical divisor class on $C$ is ($\deg(P) - 3$) times the hyperplane class $H$, but I'm not sure why this can help me construct the family of holomorphic differentials of $C$ forming a basis for the space of holomorphic differentials on $C$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at Griffiths's *Introduction to Algebraic Curves*?

Comment: Nope, I haven't been able to find it in my college library. I've looked throw Kirwan's Complex Algebraic Curves, but not much came out of it.

Comment: Would I possibly be correct in saying that because, in this case, if we consider the following on the affine part of $C$ given by $P(u,v,1)=0$ 

$$ 
\omega = \frac{du}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial v} (u,v,1)} 
$$

Then, by noting that on the curve $C$ given by $P=0$ then we have that by using the chain rule

$$
du \frac{\partial P}{\partial u} + dv \frac{\partial P}{\partial v} =0 
$$

then that on the affine part of $C$ $\omega$ is holomorphic. So we need only consider then $\omega$ at infinity. If we rewrite $\omega$ taking this into account, then

Comment: $$ 
\omega = \frac{-w^{n-3}dw}{\frac{\partial P}{\partial v}(1,v,w)}
$$

which has a zero of order $n-3$ at 0. Does this mean that in the change of co-ordinates when $z \neq 0$  then we get that there is a pole of order at most $n-3$ here? I'm not exactly sure why this means that for a canonical divisor $\kappa$ that $\kappa \sim (n-3)H$ where $H$ is a hyperplane divisor. 
Does this possible existence of a pole of order at most $n-3$ mean then that we need to multiply by polynomials of degree $n-3$ to ensure that any possible pole is cancelled out?

Comment: This is on the right track, except I wouldn't say that setting $df=0$ on $f=0$ is the chain rule. :) I'll try to write a brief answer here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As you suggested, let's work on the affine portion $w\ne 0$ of the curve $P=0$, and let's put $p(u,v)=P(u,v,1)$. Assume $\deg P = n$. Let $Q$ be any homogeneous polynomial of degree $n-3$, and set $q(u,v) = Q(u,v,1)$.

Because $C$ is a smooth curve, we know that $dp = \dfrac{\partial p}{\partial u}du+\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial v}dv$ does not vanish (as a $1$-form on $\Bbb C^2$) at points of $C$. Thus, at each point of $C$, either $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial u}$ or $\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial v}$ is nonzero. Thus, the $1$-form
$$\frac{du}{\partial p/\partial v} = - \frac{dv}{\partial p/\partial u}$$
is well-defined and holomorphic on the affine portion of $C$.

What happens when we consider $\omega = q(u,v)\dfrac{du}{\partial p/\partial v}$? It is certainly holomorphic on the affine part of $C$. (In fact, this would be true for a polynomial $q$ of any degree?) But what happens at $\infty$, i.e., when $w=0$? Now we assume that $[0,1,0]\notin C$ and use $(v',w')$, with $v'=v/u$ and $w'=1/u$ as our local coordinates near such points. In other words, $u=1/w'$ and $v=v'/w'$. Thus, in these coordinates, we have
$$\omega = \frac{q(1/w',v'/w')(-1/w'^2)dw'}{\partial p/\partial v (1/w',v'/w')}=-\frac{w'^{n-3}q(1/w',v'/w')}{w'^{n-1}\partial p/\partial v (1/w',v'/w')}dw'.$$
But because $\deg q\le n-3$ and $\deg(\partial p/\partial v)\le n-1$, we see that both the numerator and denominator are polynomials. To see that $\omega$ is holomorphic at points with $w'=0$, we need to make sure the denominator doesn't vanish at such points. In these coordinates, $C$ is given by $\tilde p(v',w') = w'^np(1/w',v'/w') = 0$, and so, by the chain rule, $\dfrac{\partial\tilde p}{\partial v'} = w^{n-1}\dfrac{\partial p}{\partial v}(1/w',v'/w')$ and smoothness of the curve tells us that this is nonzero. (Well, it might be, but then switch to the other formula for $\omega$.)

If you work through this carefully, you understand that if the degree of $Q$ is any greater, we will end up with a pole at infinity.

To say that $\kappa\sim (n-3)H$ is to say that a meromorphic $1$-form on $C$ has poles at worst of order $n-3$ on the hyperplane (line) section of $C$ at infinity.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure why this then means that $\kappa \sim (n-3)H$. I understand that a a meromorphic $1$-form on $C$ will have at worst poles of order n-3 at $\infty$ which appear unless we have the polynomial factor $q$ in the numerator. But I don't quite follow exactly how this shows the equivalence?

Comment: I don't know the approach of your course, but elements of the linear system $|D|$ are meromorphic functions $f$ with $(f)+D\ge 0$, i.e., with $(f)\ge -D$.